# Get Post ID of current user using SQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using the code below to retrieve the post id of the current user from my database. Unfortunately it does not seem to be working.

```
global $wpdb;
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
$count = $wpdb->query('SELECT ID From'. $wpdb->posts .  'WHERE post_author = "'.$user_ID.'" AND post_type = "job_listing"');
echo $count . $user_ID. "comments"; ?>
```

$user_ID and "comments" display, but $count does not. I ran this query on SQL and it works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not all variables can be `echo`ed. For arrays, you must `print_r`.

Comment: Are you sure $count is not displayed? Is not it possible that it is displayed, just you concatenate it with the id and cannot distinguish between the id and the count?

Comment: @larsAnders print_r does not work.

Comment: @Shadow I am positive, I even tried displaying them separately, but nothing is displayed

Comment: Ok, so try `var_dump` and see what type of variable it is - also, do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: @larsAnders I do not. The variable $count comes back as NULL, which makes sense as I believe there is a issue querying the database.

Comment: Could be spaces - `'SELECT ID From'. $wpdb->posts .  'WHERE` may need to be `'SELECT ID From '. $wpdb->posts .  ' WHERE`

Comment: @larsAnders You were right! It was the spaces, throwing the query off, thank you!

Comment: Wrap your query in double quotes `"`: `$count = $wpdb->query("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_author = $user_ID AND post_type = 'job_listing'");` And it should work.

Answer (score -1):

The spaces were throwing off the query, the correct query is

```
$count = $wpdb->query('SELECT ID From '. $wpdb->posts .  ' WHERE post_author = "'.$user_ID.'" AND post_type = "job_listing"');
```

Credit goes to @larsAnders

Answer (score -1):

For post id by the current user

```
    $sql='SELECT * From '. $wpdb->posts . ' WHERE post_author = "'.$user_ID.'" AND post_type = "job_listing"';
    $totalposts = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
foreach($totalpost as $userpost):
$post_id=$userpost[ID];
//if required you can get another field too
endforeach
```

Count total posts by current user id.

```
<?php global $wpdb;
    $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
    $sql='SELECT count(*) From '. $wpdb->posts . ' WHERE post_author = "'.$user_ID.'" AND post_type = "job_listing"';
    $count = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
    echo $count ."posts by " $user_ID. "comments";?>//give the total post count
```

> try this one

Comment: previous post was posted before arrange, sorry for that and immediately i have correct that. then it give output as count and user_id